# string to variable in R

Tags: string, r, variables

I'm working on an algorithm that R contains 22 raster cells. These are being stored in memory. Each variable name that gun vector.

```
var_names <- c(list1,list2,list3,list4)
```

I use the following function, but it makes me only the first member in the vector variable.

```
eval(parse(text=var_names))
```

I need all the elements of the vector become variables.

Comment: Can you give a better example of what is in list1, etc.? and what you are really trying to accomplish?  Generally there are better options than using `parse(text=`, but without knowing more precisely what you are trying to accomplish it is hard to give a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
list1 <- list2 <- list3 <- list4 <- list(1,2)
var_names <- c("list1","list2","list3","list4")
sapply(var_names, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))

     list1 list2 list3 list4
[1,] 1     1     1     1    
[2,] 2     2     2     2
```

Comment: Even though the OP's question is still pretty vague, you should probably add a token warning that `eval(parse())` is frequently not the best option, so that people finding this question later aren't terribly misled.